# Exponential growth rates in the limit

Tags: calculus

In the expression below:

$\underset{t \to \infty}{\lim} \left[\beta^t \right] \left[\frac{\partial U(x(t), y(t))}{\partial x} \cdot x(t) \right] = 0 $

With $\beta \in (0,1)$. I have been told that the condition requires that the growth rate of the term in the second bracket does not increase faster than or equal to $\frac{1}{\beta}$. I take it this means that $\underset{t \to \infty}{\lim} \beta^t$ decreases at a rate $\frac{1}{\beta}$, but I do not know how to show it. I thought of taking logs but then I get the rate $\ln(\beta)$, and not $\frac{1}{\beta}$. Is there an easy way to show this? I am sure it is very simple.

Thank you.